# Hello , Permute method in java

Tags: java

I have tried it a permute  method like in c(procedure) but it did't work also i don't understand why it must be static

```
  public class permute {
     public static void permute(int a,int b){
    int x=a;
    a=b;
    b=x;
}
    public static void main(String[] args){
    int a=2;int b=4;
    System.out.println("a= "+a+"b= "+b);
    permute(a,b);
    System.out.println("a= "+a+"b= "+b);


}
```

}

Comment: But this also doesn't work in C (unless you pass `int *` instead of `int`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your 'permute' method won't work in `C` either. Both C and Java are `pass by value`. 
You are only swapping the variables locally in that method. The swapped values are not reflected in the caller's copy of those variables.

For C, use pointers.

`void permute(int * a, int * b)`.

For Java, use Integer objects instead of primitive int.

`public static void permute(Integer a, Integer b)`

Finally, if you don't want this method to be declared static in Java, you need to create an instance of your class and call the method on that object. You can't call a non-static method in a static context.

Comment: @MajdiChebil, if my answer helped, please do not forget to upvote it and mark it correct.

Comment: Just i would like to understand more why it's not possible to call a non static method in static contest

Comment: @MajdiChebil ,that's by OOP design for Java.

Comment: Sorry , but it didn't work the permute method :    public class permute {
    public static void permute(Integer a,Integer b){
        int x=a;
        a=b;
        b=x;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a=2;int  b=4;
        System.out.println("a= "+a+"b= "+b);
        permute(a,b);
        System.out.println("a= "+a+"b= "+b);

        
    }

    
}a= 2  b= 4
a= 2 b= 4

Comment: In your `main` method, you need to declare a and b as `Integer`, not `int`.